# Issues with getRoot Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am having problems deploying a script as a web app. Here is the extremely simplified version of what I want to accomplish.

```
function doGet (e) {
   var userRoot = DocsList.getRootFolder(); 
   var myTftUnits = DocsList.getFolderById('folderId');
   myTftUnits.addToFolder(userRoot);          
}
```

I have the permissions set to run as the user and it is available to eveyone in my domain. 
I basically want the function to write a shared folder to the user's root folder. However, I keep getting the error:

> You do not have permission to perform that action.

However, the files are shared (as editors) and yet I still get the error.  Could someone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be possible for a user to share their entire drive with another user. Instead you'll need to share specific files or folders.

Comment: Yeah...I can see why this could be an issue. Thanks!